# Sending email with javax.mail: the newer version of the library brings unexpected errors

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

In the past I have used many times javax.mail to send emails in my programs, without any problems. The version I was using is 1.4.5

Now I have downloaded the latest version of the library (1.6.5 - which is now called jakarta.mail) from here: eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail, but i have problems using it. This is my code (it does not change when changing libraries):

```
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");

            Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            };

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, authenticator);    
            session.setDebug(true);        
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(cc));
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender, senderName));
            message.setSubject(oggetto);            
            message.setText(testo);

            Transport.send(message);
```

This is what i get when sending the message using the "new library" (I have activated the session debug):

```
DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 1.6.5
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=10.255.59.13, user=mmiorandi, password=<null>
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "10.255.59.13", port 25, isSSL false
220 vinfosynapp01 ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "10.255.59.13", port: 25
EHLO IS01.Infosyn.com
250-vinfosynapp01
250-SIZE
250-AUTH LOGIN
250 HELP
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=10.255.59.13, user=smtp@infosyn4.loc, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Authentication failed. Restarting authentication process.

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
...
```

And this is waht i get when using the "old" one:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "10.255.59.13", port 25, isSSL false
220 vinfosynapp01 ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "10.255.59.13", port: 25

EHLO IS01.Infosyn.com
250-vinfosynapp01
250-SIZE
250-AUTH LOGIN
250 HELP
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
...
```

The first difference that I can see is the "check mechanism": LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 vs LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM.
Could it somehow be the problem?

Comment: Which version where you previously using, and which version are you using now? BTW: The link you use is out-of-date, the project is now located at https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/ under the new name JakartaMail. Also please post the full exception stacktrace, and enable debugging in JavaMail, and include the debug output.

Comment: As said before, unfortunately i don't know what library the older one is (the file is from 2013). Ok, i have downloaded the jakarta.mail but i get the same error (i have edited the question to include the full stacktrace). What is debugging in JavaMail and how can i activate it?

Comment: If you want to debug then just set the mail.debug property to true.. Are you sure that your code is not now accessing SMTP now over SSL and that is why the code no longer functions?

Comment: Yes, turn on [Session debugging](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) and compare the output between the old library and the new library.  Are you connecting to a Exchange mail server?

Comment: Thanks to the debugging i found out i was using javax.mail 1.4.5 - the code is the same as before. Yes we are connecting to an Exchange mail server. The difference i see from debugging is a "DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded" vs a "DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed", followed by the javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Authentication failed...

Comment: Q: Did you set `mail.smtp.starttls.enable= false`?

Comment: Yes FoggyDay, i tried but nothing changed. I have edited the original question including full debug output. Thanks

Comment: "When using DIGEST-MD5 authentication, you'll also need to supply an appropriate realm; your mail administrator can supply this information. You can set this using the mail.smtp.sasl.realm property, or the setSASLRealm method on SMTPTransport" From : https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Comment: Both libraries ar using DIGEST-MD5, so i don't think the probles is there. The only difference i see is that the new one also uses XOAUTH2. I've changed the mechanism adding "properties.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM");", but i get the same "DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed" as before

Comment: I don't know if it can help, but our system administrator told me that we aren't using an Exchange mail server, but an SMTP relay, with hMailServer program

Comment: Have a look at https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2k . I think you need to set some new properties there for the XOAUTH2 i.e for one mail.imap.auth.mechanisms

Comment: mkane, is the link not working? Anyway, I have modified the mechanisms to make it equal as the working version ("LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM"), but i still have the same error

Comment: That link should be https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2 . I am unable to edit the comment for some reason

Answer (score 2):

This exception is thrown when the connect method on a Store or Transport object fails due to an authentication failure (e.g., bad user name or password).

Try to change the port to 587.

Try this as well.

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
    }
});
```

Also, if you're using google based web mail, you need to ensure that you disable the less secure apps. Just click below link and disable security settings.

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Hi, butterchoke! I'm not using a web based mail, we have a mail server (the host is an IP: 10.255.59.13, 587). The port 25 is correct: if i try to change it, i get this error "com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: 10.255.59.13, 587; timeout -1;" The code you suggested doesn't change much (after all it looks like it does the same things as mine). The strange thing is that with the "old" .jar library, everything was working fine (so the connection data must be correct), but with the "new" javax.mail.jar i get that authentication error

Comment: @butterchoke: +1: good advice.  ADDITIONAL SUGGESTIONS: 1) `properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false"); `. 2) Ask administrator to verify IP `10.255.59.13`, port `25`, username and password.  3)  Turn on session debugging: `java -Dmail.debug=true ...`

Answer (score 0):

We have tried so many things, but sadly we could't find any solution other than allow unauthenticated acces on the SMTP relay to the server where the process has to run

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
```